# How to pass argument to "find" from docker?

Tags: powershell, docker

I am experimenting some idea.

I have a ubuntu docker container running on Windows. I want to use the `find` command inside the container to scan my Windows directory.

I did this from powershell:

```
docker --rm -v c:\test:/data run ubuntu find /data -type f
```

It works well. But if I want to pass argument to `-exec` option, like this

```
docker --rm -v c:\test:/data run ubuntu find /data -type f -exec dos2unix {} \;
```

I got **find: missing argument to `-exec'** error. I suspect that powershell mess up with `{} \;`, but I could not find a way escape it.

Comment: Try `sh -c "your find command with exec"`

Comment: @user2915097 It works ;) Please convert it to an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a shell to execute that command, so try

`sh -c "your find command with exec"`